# Use debian desktop as bluetooth speaker

Tags: bluetooth

I have got my desktop debian working as a bluetooth speaker (pair with phone, on phone start an audio stream, not I can listen on desktop, pause, resume, see title).

However, I am wondering if there is a better way to control it.
The buttons are small, The pause/play button is next to other buttons that should not be pressed, and it is all in the bluetooth menu.

I would like to have buttons, preferably in the tray, like the media control buttons for the media player on this device (the desktop). Alternatively command line control: I could then put together some buttons myself.